# Text isn't being split properly

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to extract both text and hex color from a string.

It currently has a small problem with the symbol ">"

Here is the code that I currently got;

```
package main.cache;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void extract(String string) { 
        final String STARTS_WITH_COLOR_LITERAL = "^[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(STARTS_WITH_COLOR_LITERAL);
        Object[] objects = Arrays.stream(string.split("<col=")).filter(part -> pattern.matcher(part).find()).toArray();
        String name;
        String color = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            String[] line = objects[i].toString().split(">");
            if (line.length == 1) {
                name = line[0];
            } else {
                color = line[0];
                name = line[1];
            }
            System.out.println("Color " + color + ", name " + name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        extract("something before<col=ff00ff>mercides> car<col=ffff00>plates");
    }
}
```

for example when passing this argument, the output is expected to be

```
Color null, name something before
Color ff00ff, name mercides> car
Color ffff00, name plates
```

The output that I currently get is

```
Color null, name something before
Color ff00ff, name mercides
Color ffff00, name plates
```

Comment: Extract only pair color/following text ? Why extract 'somehing before'  there is no color ?

Comment: Do not use regex to parse HTML. Use an html/xml parser

Comment: You're splitting each part by `>`. So the `>` are no longer part of the text. Your second split has *three* parts, not two.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah I know, and I don't know how to overcome this problem to get it to print the expected result.

Comment: You should listen to the advice of @Jens, and not use a regular expression for this. HTML is not suited for this. In any case, your regular expression for `STARTS_WITH_A_COLOR_LITERAL` is also wrong, that's why you get the first part which doesn't have a color. Parse using a (lenient) HTML parser, collect all the nodes between `color` nodes, and that will be more readable and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for pairs `color/name` (in this order) you can use : `(?><col=(?<color>[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})>)?(?<text>(?><.*?>)?[^<]+)`

```
static void extract(String string) {
    Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("(?><col=(?<color>[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})>)?(?<name>(?><.*?>)?[^<]+)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (m.find()) {
        String color = m.group("color");
        String name = m.group("name");
        System.out.printf("Color %s, name %s\n", color, name);
    }
}
/*
Color null, name something before
Color ff00ff, name mercides> car
Color ffff00, name plates
```

---

Regex details, see [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U359tu/1) for long details (look explanation on the right)

1. `(?><col=(?<color>[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})>)?` is for the color, starts with `<col` and ends with `>` with hexa chars inside, it's optionnal so there is a `?` at the end
2. `(?<text>(?><.*?>)?[^<]+)` group for the name, can have another balise in, but the last char can be a `<`